# Plugin should use a background thread ( Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' )

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic4

i am trying to use cordova keychain [plugin][1] for ios, inside my ionic application. but facing this error

> 6:48 PM2020-07-14 18:44:32.456726+0500 Farsh[1817:53270] THREAD
> WARNING: ['Keychain'] took '14.635986' ms. Plugin should use a
> background thread. 2020-07-14 18:44:32.456767+0500 Farsh[1817:55957]
> -[NSNull boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8062d9d0 2020-07-14 18:44:32.614153+0500 Farsh[1817:55957] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull boolValue]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8062d9d0'
> *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e5dc34
> -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132 3 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e4190c **forwarding** + 1436 4 CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff23e43bf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120 5 Farsh
> 0x000000010e66aac0 __19-[CDVKeychain set:]_block_invoke + 432 6
> libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010e9c7f11 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>
> - 12 7 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010e9c8e8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8 8 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010e9cb2d8
>   _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1022 9 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010e9da399 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 351 10
>   libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010e9daca6 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 135 11
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff51c089f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220 12
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff51c07b77 start_wqthread + 15 )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

and my application crashed after this. Is there anyone know how to solve this problem ??
Please answer
Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keychain

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I had the same problem and the issue was that I didn't explicitly set a value for the `useTouchId` parameter. This bug is [known](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ios-keychain/issues/34) since 2018 and still not fixed. Shows you how good ionic is as an ecosystem and how much the people care  Worse is that even the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keychain)(!) have an incorrect example:

#### Wrong

```
this.keychain.set(key, value).then(() => { ... }
```

#### Correct

```
this.keychain.set(key, value, false).then(() => { ... }
```

Adding the third parameter should fix your issues.